# Console app client to Service Fabric Stateless Service

Tags: c#, azure, console, azure-service-fabric, stateless

I'm learning SF, and am now trying to build a console client to a stateless service.

tried to follow instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services

and added this to my StatelessService class

```
    public interface IMyService : IService
    {
        Task<string> HelloWorldAsync();
    }
```

and a simple implementation

```
    public Task<string> HelloWorldAsync()
    {
        return Task.FromResult("HELLO FROM SERVICE!");
    }
```

The rest is unchanged.

In my Console app I have

```
IMyService helloWorldClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IMyService>(
   new Uri("fabric:/RestGateway/StatelessGateway1"));
string message = await helloWorldClient.HelloWorldAsync();
```

The service deployed to my local cluster and seems to work fine (green button) but I get an Exception when calling helloWorldClient.HelloWorldAsync().

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to add a communication listener to your service like this:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    yield return new ServiceInstanceListener(ServiceRemotingExtensions.CreateServiceRemotingListener(this, Context));
}
```

**Note:**

The call to `CreateServiceRemotingListener` creates a specific [communication listener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication) that can be used only from within the cluster. So, when talking from your dev machine to a service running on your dev cluster this will work. You can't talk to services running on different machines like this.

To access your cluster from the outside, you could use [ServiceBus](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.ServiceBus), [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf) or [OWIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi) for instance. (or something you build yourself)

Comment: OK The purpose was to create a really simple client (ie a console app) which would ultimately cause SF Actors to react to incoming messages. I thought creating a StatelessService was the simplest relay "into" the cluster.  Would it be an easier route to create a REST-API Service and call that from the client? I just want an easy path in to the cluster for testing/learning.

Comment: Yes, if the client can be outside the cluster you'll need to use the alternative ways I mentioned. Depending on your requirements, knowledge and preference, any will do.